# nginx reverse proxy disable cache

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, no-cache

i use nginx as a reverse proxy to connect a api. The problem is when i send a query after add or remove something. Nginx send me the old json value. I tried to disabled cache but it's not working.

my nginx config:

```
location  / {

  sendfile off;
  add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
  add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
  if_modified_since off;
  expires off;
  etag off;
  proxy_no_cache 1;
  proxy_cache_bypass 1;

  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header HTTPS   $https;
}
```

i tried query without nginx and all work well in console

thank you!

Comment: Is the back-end application caching it?

Comment: No, when i do query in console server. It's send All time the good json

Comment: finally, it is my backend... i make some mistake with closing session in my database.

Answer (score 21):

According to the documentation [proxy_cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache) you have to replace

```
proxy_no_cache 1;
proxy_cache_bypass 1;
```

**proxy_no_cache** and **proxy_cache_bypass** defines conditions under which the response will not be saved to a cache.

Then to disable the cache, you can replace these two condition with

proxy_cache off;

Here a full exemple that you can use to configure a proxy for a stateless api server

```
location /myapi {

        # Proxy 
        proxy_set_header                X-Localhost true;
        proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass                      http://localhost:8080/myapi;

        proxy_redirect                  off;
        proxy_buffers                   32 16k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size         64k;
        proxy_cache                     off;


        # Headers for client browser NOCACHE + CORS origin filter 
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        expires off;
        add_header    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' always;

        allow all;
    }
```

Comment: After upgrade to ES 7.7 I was missing "proxy_cache off". You made my day man, thank you so much!

Comment: @bdzzaid by default caching is disabled. So one could skip the caching-directives, right?

Comment: @wuarmin Yes you can with proxy_cache_bypass but you have to define conditions under which the response will not be taken from a cache.